# Creating "Then I scroll down (x,y)" scenario Visual Studio Selenium Specflow

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, webdriver, specflow

Basically, I'm creating automated testing for a system that already has many Step Definitions set up (though for the life of me I cannot figure out where these files are)...

So, I can do "Given I navigate to (url) Then I click the element (x) ..." etc. and the tests run fine. Great.

I'm using the ChromeDriver, and for elements on the bottom half of the page, unless the window can see those elements (which it can't) it will just assume they're not there and after a set time, give up and close.

So, I'm thinking it makes sense to implement a scroll function. Pretty simple, I imagined.

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace (nameofmyprojectwhichincludestestscenarios)
{
    [Binding]
    public class HomePageLandingFunctionality_Steps
    {

        [Given(@"I scroll down on ""(.*), (.*)""")]

        public void GivenIScrollDownOn(int x, int y)
        {
            {
                IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                IJavaScriptExecutor js = Instance as IJavaScriptExecutor;
                js.ExecuteScript("scroll(0, 250);");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cool! So Given I navigate to (url)
Then I scroll down (0, 500)

You would expect it to navigate to the URL then scroll down 500 pixels to the bottom half of the website. Well it doesn't. It either opens up a new chrome driver that redirects to nothing (it just shows data:,) or if I tweak it enough (it's been a long day, I can't remember exactly what I was doing) it will open up the website in a separate browser and then immediately close.

The webdriver file is located in a separate project under the same solution. I tried creating a static "using" reference at the top of my file to that project and subsequent webdriver file, then using the variable name assigned to the webdriver used to run the other Scenarios that I told you I could not locate earlier. No dice.

Sorry if this question is all over the place. I'm pretty unfamiliar with how their system is set up which is why I think I'm so confused. If I can clarify in any way please let me know.

Comment: The code does what you instructed it to do: 'new ChromeDriver();' This creates a new ChromeDriver object with the default configs. What you *probably* want is to re-use the existing ChromeDriver object, that is set up somewhere else in the code. But given that you're not using this object in the method, can't be sure of that. As well, what is 'Instance'?

Comment: @Buxter Instance is the webdriver that all the other tests use to execute the Specflow tests I wrote. It's actually located in a different project but exists in the same solution I'm working in. Sorry for all the confusion... this system was set up a while back and I've only been here for a week so I'm a little confused figuring out what everything is for/where the things I am looking for are located.

Comment: Well, then you definitely don't need this line: 'IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();'